# JLabel not showing when called in paint method

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, java-2d

I have the following code:

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel{
 JLabel label = new JLabel();
 public void init()
    {
        label.setSize(100, 100);
        label.setLocation(10, 10);
        label.setText("lalallaalal");
        this.add(label);
    }
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

                paintRoad(g);
                paintBorders(g);

                paintEnemies(g, enemies);
                paintPlayer(g);
    }
```

I want the label to be redrawn every time the `JPanel` is repainted, but when I put `this.add(label)` at the end of `paint` method it doesn't show the label.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paint()` invokes `paintComponent()`. It's better to override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

[A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: @Brajit worked that way, but the interesting thing is that when I add the label in the init() method, the label is placed at a different location that it is set to. But when I called it in paintComponent() it is placed where it should be. Why is that?

Comment: `paintComponent` method is where all of your painting code should be placed. It is true that this method will be invoked when it is time to paint.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the JLabel, try using the *drawString(String str, int X, int y)* method in the paint method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(label.getText(), 110, 110);
}
```